# Python XlsxWriter Protect Worksheet

Tags: xlsxwriter

How to protect an excel worksheet by allowing sort autofilter using python xlsxwriter
i tried the following code

```
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('TEST')
ws.protect('abcd@09',{'sort':True,'autofilter':True})
/* Data Written to  ws*/
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

That code works but may not be doing what you expect. When I ran it I got the following that shows the `sort` and `autofilter` enabled:

[image]

If you want to have them protected then just leave them in the default/false condition.

Comment: But i am not able to sort the worksheet and also apply filter on the 1st row , every time it says the work sheet is protected

Comment: The dialog in the screenshot shows that the Sort and Autofilter are enabled. What do you see when you run the examaple? Also, what version of XlsxWriter are you using?